# Numpy averaging with multi-dimensional weights along an axis

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy array, `a`, `a.shape=(48,90,144)`. I want to take the weighted average of `a` along the first axis using the weights in array `b`, `b.shape=(90,144)`. So the output should be a numpy array of shape `(48,)`.

I know this can be done with a list comprehension:

```
np.array([np.average(a[i], weights=b) for i in range(48)])
```

But I'd like to avoid having to convert from a list back to a numpy array.

Can anyone help? I'm sure this is possible using numpy functions and slicing, but I'm stuck. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In a single line:

```
np.average(a.reshape(48, -1), weights=b.ravel()), axis=1)
```

You can test it with:

```
a = np.random.rand(48, 90, 144)
b = np.random.rand(90,144)
np.testing.assert_almost_equal(np.average(a.reshape(48, -1),
                                          weights=b.ravel(), axis=1),
                               np.array([np.average(a[i],
                                                    weights=b) for i in range(48)]))
```

Answer (score 0):

That was the fasted I could come up with:

```
(a * b).mean(-1).mean(-1) * (b.size / b.sum())
```

It can be fit for any number of source and result dimensions.

Reshape and 1 x mean did not further speed up:

```
(a * b).reshape(len(a), -1).mean(-1) * (b.size / b.sum())
```